# How to make a loop that adds the number the user input stop after user inputs "stop" (Python)

Tags: python

#This is the question I am trying to do:
'''You are going to write a function shoppingTrip() that calculates the total cost of a shopping trip by adding up the cost of the items, subtracting the discounts, and adding in the tax to find the new total.
Since the number of items on the shopping trip is unknown, you will use a while loop to ask the user to input the cost of each item (which should be a float).  The user will enter “stop” when all items have been entered.  At that point, your program will ask the user to input the discount as a percentage, and then input the tax rate as a percentage.  Your program will print out the total cost of the shopping trip at the end, rounded to two decimal places. '''

This is my code:

**

```
def shoppingTrip ():
    userinps = input("Enter cost of item ('stop' to finish):")
    total = float(userinps)
    while userinps != "stop":
        userinps = input("Enter cost of item ('stop' to finish):")
        total = total + float(userinps)
    if userinps == "stop":
        inp2 = float(input("Enter sale discount as a percentage"))
        inp3 = float(input("Enter the tax rate as a percentage"))
        final = (total * ((100-inp2)/100)) # calculating discount
        finalcost = (final * ((100 + inp3)/100)) #tax rate
        roundcost = round(finalcost,2)
        print("The Total Cost is $", roundcost)
```

**

What I got is a value error:

File "/Users/nathanielpranata/Documents/hw3/hw3Code.py", line 130, in shoppingTrip
total = total + float(userinps)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'stop'

Comment: If the user entered `stop`, break the loop, before attempting to add to the total.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

`total=0
while True:
    user_input = input("Please input a number: ")
    if user_input == "stop":
        break
    else:
        user_input = int(user_input)
        total += user_input`

Comment: What if my teacher say that I need to use a while loop for the stop statement and not an if cause that's what she just said.